# How do I add a custom property to "Get-ADUser"?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I'm trying to Output information I pull from AD with `Get-ADUser` which is fairly straight forward, however, I am trying to add the primarysmtp address from Get-Mailbox into that array and am running into a world of problems.

Basically I have:

```
$newuser = Get-ADUser $Username -properties Name, DisplayName, GivenName, Surname
```

I wish to add a custom property to `$newuser` just for the output, not to the actual ADUser.

```
$EXmail = (Get-Mailbox $Username).PrimarySmtpAddress
```

How can I add `$EXmail` to `$newuser`?
Would like it to just add `Email : $EXMail` as a property somehow..

Tried `$newuser | Add-member`, no luck.
I tried `$newuser.GetEnumerator()` and adding to that, no luck.
I'm hoping there is a way to do this with `GetEnumerator()` and just add a Key/Value as working that into my script would be the easiest.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: Why not just `Select-Object` and choose the properties (including [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)) that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Add-Member` should work for this but you need the `-Force` switch since there is a conflict with `Email` as a property name.

```
$newuser | Add-Member -MemberType Noteproperty -Name "Email" -Value $EXmail -Force
```

An alternative is to use `Select-Object` and you won't have to change `$newuser` object at all.

```
$newuser | Select-Object Name,DisplayName,GivenName,Surname,@{n="Email";e={$EXMail}}
```

Comment: Thanks. This definitely does the job. Only issue I have now is GetEnumerator() method does not work on this object.. Might have to rework my output code which uses $_.Key and $_.Value.. hopefully won't be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
$newuser = Get-ADUser $Username -properties Name, DisplayName, GivenName, Surname, @{n='PrimarySmtpAddress';e={(Get-Mailbox $_.userprincipalname).PrimarySmtpAddress}}
```

Comment: When I try that I get an error: Get-ADUser : One or more properties are invalid.
Parameter name: System.Collections.Hashtable

Comment: As @BillStewart suggested the calculated property should be used within a piped `| Select-Object -Property *,@{n='EXmail';e={(Get-Mailbox $_.userprincipalname).PrimarySmtpAddress}}`